# convert string to list

Tags: python, list

I have a string like this:

```
st = "The most basic data structure in Python is the sequence * Each element of a sequence is assigned a number * its position or index * The first index is zero * the second index is one * and so forth *"
```

and I want to split into the list like this:

```
ls =["The most basic data structure in Python is the sequence","Each element of a sequence is assigned a number","its position or index",.....]
```

I'm just started python, please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can split a string by a character:

```
yourString = "Hello * my name * is * Alex"
yourStringSplitted = yourString.split('*')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the function `str.split` to split a string into a array on a specific character :

```
>>> str.split(st,"*")
['The most basic data structure in Python is the sequence ',
 ' Each element of a sequence is assigned a number ',
 ' its position or index ',
 ' The first index is zero ',
 ' the second index is one ',
 ' and so forth ',
 '']
```